# can not read property of undefined when it is defined properly in express

Tags: express

I have a POST request (content-type: text/plain) with this body: `{"initObj":{"UDID":"123456"}}`

It shows *"Cannot read property 'UDID' of undefined"*

When I do this:

```
console.log(req.body);
```

It shows the request body correctly, but when I do this:

```
console.log(req.body.initObj);
```

it shows `undefined`

Here is the configuration of the server:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //true

// override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in req
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
```

Comment: Can you try `console.log(req.body['initObj'])` ?

Comment: i tried but same result it is undefined

Comment: i also tried  JSON.stringify(req.body); console.log(req.body.initObj); but returns undefined the problem when i test whith http requester and put the content type application/json it returns the result correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upload the data as `text/plain`, `req.body` will be a *string* (containing some JSON text, but because it's uploaded as text, `body-parser` won't parse it into a proper object). And strings don't have a property called `initObj`.

You should either parse the data yourself:

```
let data = JSON.parse(req.body);
console.log(data.initObj);
```

Or upload as `application/json` (which makes more sense to me).